# How to substitute/delete a new line (\n)?

Tags: text-processing, busybox

I got access to `busybox 1.27.2` only.

I'm currently processing a dictionary with more than half a million words and more than 6,000 pages (which was extracted from a PDF with ghostscript and converted to plain text). Is in a `20MB` `.txt` file. Originally, every single word in this dictionary has a leading `->` to make it easier to search for a word.

What I am trying to achive is to make it `*nix` friendly. Meaning that if I do this:
`grep -e '->myfancyword' ./dictionary.txt`.

I should get as a result:

```
->fancyword: This is a very fancy word. *Definition going on for more than 6 lines*
```

That's easily done by stripping al newlines `\n` so every word will have all of its definition on a very long line, which is ok. I can replace all `\n` with `tr -d '\n'` and then have the output of that going through `sed 's/->/\n->/g'` so I'll be ending up with all word's definition on a single line. Even on this huge document, its something that's done in less than 5 seconds.

I am almost getting the result I want, but is not perfect. I can do this `grep -e '->word' ./dictionary.txt` and get the full definition of the word. But it is not cosmetically perfect.

The reason why I'm not pleased with the output is because the original pdf was formatted to be printed on `A4` pages, meaning that when there is a long word, it's chopped. Like this:

e.g

```
->word: This is a defini-
tion.
```

If I process the file with the previous work flow, I got: `->word: This is a defini- tion.` when grepping the desired word.

So far what I managed to accomplish is this:

1. input

```
->firstword: This is a defini-
tion.
->secondword: This is a second defini-
tion.
```

2. applied
   `tr -d '\n' < ./dictionary.txt > ./dictionary2.txt`
3. output is:

```
->firstword: This is a defini- tion. ->secondword: This is a second defini- tion.
```

4. ran: `sed -e 's/->/\n->/g' ./dictionary2.txt`
5. Ending up with:

output

```
->firstword: This is a defini- tion.
->secondword: This is a second defini- tion.
```

Before even doing the second step I would like to remove the dash and new line (`-\n`) to "join" all chopped lines together.

**So, my question is: How can I substitute/delete the specific string containing the dash `-` and the newline char `\n` (`-\n`) at the end of the line?**

What I like to get is:

output (please, do check the dash and space (`-` ) not being present anymore)

```
->firstword: This is a definition.
->secondword: This is a second definition.
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

This is a page of the PDF file:

```
     ->abigeato. (Del lat. abigeatus). 1. m. Am. Hurto de ganado.
     ->abigeo. (Del lat. abigeus). 1. m. Am. Ladrón de ganado.
     ->abigotado, da. 1. adj. bigotudo.
     ->abinar. 1. tr. rur. y vulg. Binar la tierra.
     ->abintestato. (De ab intestato). 1. m. Der. Procedimiento judicial sobre herencia y
   adjudicación de bienes de quien muere sin testar.
     ->abiogénesis. (De a-2, bio- y -génesis). 1. f. Producción hipotética de seres vivos par-
   tiendo de materia inerte. 2. f. Bioquím. síntesis abiótica.
     ->abiótico, ca. 1. adj. Biol. Se dice del medio en que no es posible la vida.  V. síntesis
   abiótica
     ->abipón, na. 1. adj. Se dice del individuo de un pueblo amerindio que habitaba cerca del
   Paraná. U. t. c. s. 2. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a los abipones. 3. m. Lengua de la familia
   guaicurú hablada por los abipones.
     ->abisagrar. 1. tr. Clavar o fijar bisagras en las puertas y sus marcos, o en otros objetos.
     ->abisal. (Del lat. abyssus). 1. adj. abismal (|| perteneciente al abismo). 2. adj. Se dice de
   las zonas del mar profundo que se extienden más allá del talud continental, y corresponden a
   profundidades mayores de 2000 m. 3. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a tales zonas.
     ->abiselar. 1. tr. biselar.
     ->abisinio, nia. 1. adj. Natural de Abisinia, hoy Etiopía. U. t. c. s. 2. adj. Perteneciente o re-
   lativo a este país de África. 3. m. Lengua abisinia.  V. rito abisinio
     ->abismado, da. (Del part. de abismar). 1. adj. Dicho de una persona, de su expresión, de
   su gesto, etc.: Ensimismados, reconcentrados. 2. adj. Heráld. Dicho de una pieza del escudo:
   Puesta en el abismo.
     ->abismal (1).  (Del ár. hisp. almismár, y este del ár. clás. mismar). 1. m. Cada uno de los
   clavos con que se fijaba en el asta el hierro de la lanza.abismal2. 1. adj. Perteneciente o re-
   lativo al abismo. 2. adj. Muy profundo, insondable, incomprensible.
     ->abismar. 1. tr. Hundir en un abismo. U. t. c. prnl. 2. tr. Confundir, abatir. U. t. c. prnl. 3.
   prnl. Entregarse del todo a la contemplación, al dolor, etc. 4. prnl. Am. sorprenderse (|| con-
   moverse con algo imprevisto o raro).
     ->abismático, ca. 1. adj. abismal2.
     ->abismo. (Quizá del lat. vulg. *abyssimus, der. de abyssus, y este del gr. , sin fondo). 1.
   m. Profundidad grande, imponente y peligrosa, como la de los mares, la de un tajo, la de una
   sima, etc. U. t. en sent. fig. Se sumió en el abismo de la desesperación. 2. m. infierno (|| lugar
   de castigo eterno). 3. m. Cosa inmensa, insondable o incomprensible. 4. m. Diferencia
   grande entre cosas, personas, ideas, sentimientos, etc. 5. m. Heráld. Punto o parte central
   del escudo. 6. m. Nic. Maldad, perdición, ruina moral.
```

This is what I get when grepping the regular text after extraction is completed with ghostscript (processed with dos2unix only):

```
grep -e '->abiog' ./rae-dos2unix.txt
     ->abiogénesis. (De a-2, bio- y -génesis). 1. f. Producción hipotética de seres vivos par-
```

This is when previous steps (1-4) are done on the text, when grepping I got:

```
grep -e '->abiog' ./rae-una-linea.txt
->abiogénesis. (De a-2, bio- y -génesis). 1. f. Producción hipotética de seres vivos par-   tiendo de materia inerte. 2. f. Bioquím. síntesis abiótica.
```

Comment: Isn't `s/- //g` *afterwards* easier? Does that sequence appear elsewhere and need to be preserved?

Comment: As someone who has converted a fair number of pdf documents to plain text, i can tell you that this is going to be a lot harder to do right than it seems.   Joining consecutive lines and removing hyphens is the easy part.  The hard part is knowing when NOT to remove the hyphens - there are many compound words that *need* that hyphen to remain in the middle of them - "short-change", is a good example. Any program which hyphenates that word to fit a page or column is going to split it at the existing hyphen.  When you re-join it, the hyphen should remain.

Comment: Fortunately, it's not that hard to find hyphenation dictionaries.   But it will complicate the algorithm a little to do a lookup for every word you de-hyphenate and join.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Yes, the sequence does appears in the middle of the line.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank you. I added a screenshot to make more sense.

Comment: @cas I doubt that will be my case. The Royal Spanish Academy (Real Academia Española) is in charge of putting the dictionary all together and in Spanish, we do have rules to not split a word if it is a "special word" like the one you described, so is unlikely for us to split "short-change" or a word with similar characteristics in Spanish.

Comment: @abacox I think what @cas meant was something different. Assume you have the phrase (example from an academic text on history) _"El movimiento anti-colonialista, reivindicador ..."_ near the end of a line. As you said, you would not split inside a constituent (i.e. you would not say _"anti-colo-\n nialista"_), but the natural way to split is would be _"anti-\n colonialista"_. However, when you remove the newline there, you want the `-` to remain in the word, i.e. the result should be "anti-colonialista" and not "anticolonialista".

Comment: @AdminBee Yes, that's exactly what I meant.   There are fairly consistent, well-known language and cultural rules for breaking and hyphenating words...it's not terribly difficult to come up with an algorithm to split words that works well 99.9+% of the time.  To do the reverse takes more than an algorithm, it requires a good dictionary of hyphenated words and phrases.  The code should compare the word/phrase it just re-joined against its dictionary and, if both are the same with all hyphens removed, replace the word/phrase with the dictionary version. And there will be other complications too.

Comment: alternatively, I guess you could run a spelling and/or grammar checker on the text after you've got rid of the hypens and newlines.   or proof-read it.  preferably have several different people proof-read it - it's hard to spot errors in text you've seen many times before.

Comment: @cas Yeah, in particular if you _wrote_ it yourself ... ;)

Comment: what's wrong with hypens? it's a perfectly good word!

Comment: @AdminBee That's absolutely right· I got a book with grammar rules. I recall one of this rules was to move the entire hyphenated word to the new line instead of splitting it as you said. So I think I'll be consulting with RAE and check that out. And because is RAE the one in charge of the dictionary is not likely for them to make a mistake, but it could happen.

Comment: Ok, that rule would of course make things easier (I am not a native spanish speaker - let alone writer, so I don't know about that). @cas absolutely no objection against hypens, I use them all the time myself ;) I was rather referring to how hard it is to spot errors in texts you not only saw many times before, but actually wrote yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly easy in perl.  perl's `-0` option tells it to use NUL characters instead of newlines as the input record separator so, unless there are NUL characters in the input, it will treat the entire input file as one record.  Even if there are NUL characters it will just keep processing subsequent records, same as the first.

Note: this does mean that the entire input file has to fit into memory - on a modern system with 16GB or more of RAM, this is unlikely to be a problem. On an older system with insufficient RAM but enough swap, it will still work but will be much slower.

```
$ cat input.txt
->firstword: This is a defini-
tion.
->secondword: This is a second defini-
tion.
```

```
$ perl -0 -p -e 's/-\s*\n//g' input.txt 
->firstword: This is a definition.
->secondword: This is a second definition.
```

This removes every sequence of a hyphen followed by zero-or-more whitespace characters (`\s`, see below), followed by a newline (`\n`).

The `\s*` part of the regex is there to match trailing whitespace characters that **might** be at the end of a line - in my experience, it's very common for text lines to have trailing whitespace (and they're difficult to spot because they're non-printing characters, i.e. invisible).   Alternatively, use  `*` (zero-or-more **space** characters) or `[ \t]*` (zero-or-more spaces-or-tabs) or `\h*` (zero-or-more **horizontal** whitespace chars) instead of `\s*`.

From `man perlre`:

> The set of characters that are deemed whitespace are those that Unicode calls "Pattern White Space", namely:
>
> ```
> U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION
> U+000A LINE FEED
> U+000B LINE TABULATION
> U+000C FORM FEED
> U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN
> U+0020 SPACE
> U+0085 NEXT LINE
> U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK
> U+200F RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK
> U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR
> U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
> ```

---

NOTES:

1. A `-` character isn't the only possible "hyphen" or "dash" character that may be in use.  Wikipedia has pages listing unicode [Hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Unicode) and [Dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Unicode) characters. Fortunately, perl has good unicode-handling capabilities , so the one-liner can be re-written to use `\p{Dash}` (or `\p{Pd}`) instead of `-` to match all of the dash category characters:

```
$ perl -0 -p -e 's/\p{Dash}\h*\n//g' input.txt 
->firstword: This is a definition.
->secondword: This is a second definition.
```

This will, however, treat em-dashes the same as hyphens (so will remove an em-dash at the end of a line, same as it would a hyphen)...and it's not uncommon to use em-dashes instead of parentheses.   You could use `\p{Hyphen}` instead of `\p{Dash}` if you don't mind a warning message about "hyphen" being deprecated. Or you could use a bracket-expression which contains only the unicode code points that you want to treat as hyphens - e.g.

```
    perl -0 -p -e 's/[\N{U+002D}\N{U+00AD}\N{U+2010}\N{U+2011}]\h*\n//g' input.txt
```

2. I recommend not having each word definition starting with `->`. That will make it unnecessarily awkward to search for a word with grep - the search string will have to be quoted (because of the `>`, which the shell uses for redirection) and preceded by `--` (because of the `-`, otherwise grep will treat your search pattern as if you meant them to be options).  e.g. you won't be able to do just:

   ```
    grep ^firstword: dictionary.txt
   ```

   Instead, you'd have to do:

   ```
    grep -- '^->firstword:' dictionary.txt
   ```

---

For a better example, I extracted the text from your image with [tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/) and run it through a version of the perl one-liner that also removes all newlines that aren't followed by `->`:

```
$ cat input2.txt 
->abigeato. (Del lat. abigeatus). 1. m. Am. Hurto de ganado.
->abigeo. (Del lat. abigeus). 1. m. Am. Ladrén de ganado.
->abigotado, da. 1. adj. bigotudo.
->abinar. 1. tr. rur. y vulg. Binar la tierra.
->abintestato. (De ab intestato). 1. m. Der. Procedimiento judicial sobre herencia y
adjudicacion de bienes de quien muere sin testar.
Eiiftiénesis. (De a-2, bio- y -génesis). 1. f. Produccién hipotética de seres vivos par-
tiendo de materia inerte. 2. f. Bioquim. sintesis abistica,
->abidtico, ca. 1. adj. Biol. Se dice del medio en que no es posible la vida. V. sintesis
abidtica
->abipon, na. 1. adj. Se dice del individuo de un pueblo amerindio que habitaba cerca del
Parana. U. t.c. s. 2. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a los abipones. 3. m. Lengua de la familia
guaicurt hablada por los abipones.
->abisagrar. 1. tr. Clavar o fijar bisagras en las puertas y sus marcos, 0 en otros objetos.
->abisal. (Del lat. abyssus). 1. adj. abismal (|| perteneciente al abismo). 2. adj. Se dice de
las zonas del mar profundo que se extienden mas alla del talud continental, y corresponden a
```

```
$ perl -0 -p -e 's/[\N{U+002D}\N{U+00AD}\N{U+2010}\N{U+2011}]\h*\n//g; s/\n+(?!->)//g' input2.txt
->abigeato. (Del lat. abigeatus). 1. m. Am. Hurto de ganado.
->abigeo. (Del lat. abigeus). 1. m. Am. Ladrén de ganado.
->abigotado, da. 1. adj. bigotudo.
->abinar. 1. tr. rur. y vulg. Binar la tierra.
->abintestato. (De ab intestato). 1. m. Der. Procedimiento judicial sobre herencia yadjudicacion de bienes de quien muere sin testar.Eiiftiénesis. (De a-2, bio- y -génesis). 1. f. Produccién hipotética de seres vivos partiendo de materia inerte. 2. f. Bioquim. sintesis abistica,
->abidtico, ca. 1. adj. Biol. Se dice del medio en que no es posible la vida. V. sintesisabidtica
->abipon, na. 1. adj. Se dice del individuo de un pueblo amerindio que habitaba cerca delParana. U. t.c. s. 2. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a los abipones. 3. m. Lengua de la familiaguaicurt hablada por los abipones.
->abisagrar. 1. tr. Clavar o fijar bisagras en las puertas y sus marcos, 0 en otros objetos.
->abisal. (Del lat. abyssus). 1. adj. abismal (|| perteneciente al abismo). 2. adj. Se dice delas zonas del mar profundo que se extienden mas alla del talud continental, y corresponden a
```

I still recommend removing the `->` sequence from the final output file.  It's a useful marker while processing the text, but problematic afterwards.

---

A comment from @zevzek solves the "uses enormous amounts of RAM" problem.  Instead of using NUL as the input record separator, use `->` as the separator.  This makes the perl script read only one word definition at a time, instead of the entire file at once.  This will make it run much faster with a very large input file because it won't be using all available RAM and causing the system to swap.

Other changes are required to the script because we're now treating the sequence of characters that marks the **beginning** of a new word definition as the **end** of the previous definition.  Specifically, we now need to:

- Change the command-line option `-p` (always output the current record) to `-n` (only output the current record when we tell it to).
- Remove the end-of-line characters (perl's `chomp()` function does this)
- Check if the input record is empty or contains only whitespace because there will now be an *imaginary* empty record before the first actual record "abigeato" and we don't want to print that out.  (Why is there suddenly an imaginary empty record? Because `->` now indicates the end of a record, not the beginning of a new one. The `->` in `->abigeato` is the separator between the previous (empty) record and the new "abigeato" record)
- print the modified record with "->" and a newline.

All together, these would change the final one-liner from this:

```
$ perl -0 -p -e 's/[\N{U+002D}\N{U+00AD}\N{U+2010}\N{U+2011}]\h*\n//g;
                 s/\n+(?!->)//g' input2.txt
```

to this:

```
perl -n -e 'BEGIN { $/="->" };
            chomp;
            next if m/^\s*$/;
            s/[\N{U+002D}\N{U+00AD}\N{U+2010}\N{U+2011}]\h*\n//g;
            s/\n+//g;
            print "->$_\n"' input2.txt
```

Output from this version is the same as the original except that the final output line is guaranteed to end with a newline (`\n`). The original did not guarantee this, in fact it prevented it by removing all newlines that weren't followed by `->`.   This is a free bonus because technically a file is only a text file in unix if every single line ends with `\n`....most of the time, this does not matter (at least, not with modern versions of standard text-processing tools), but some programs don't correctly handle the final line of a "text file" if it doesn't end with `\n`.

(BTW, the original could be fixed by adding an END block to add a newline back to the end of the output: `END { print "\n" }`)

`$/` is a perl variable which defines the input record separator (see `man perlvar` for details on perl's pre-defined/special/controlling variables), similar to the `RS` variable in `awk`.  Previously, I was using perl's `-0` option to set it to the NUL character (see `man perlrun` for details on perl's command-line options).

`BEGIN` statements happen once at the beginning of a script, before and outside of the implicit `while(<>) { ..... }` loop caused by using perl's `-p` or `-n` options (which make perl behave kind of like a super-powered `sed` or `sed -n` respectively).  Similarly, an `END` statement happens once at the end of a script, after all input has been read and processed.

Comment: Thank you. My system got 4GB of RAM but swap should not be a problem, I'll be dedicating a couple of Gigabytes for that. Even if this takes some time to complete I truly believe its so awesome to process this huge wealth of information with old home computers. Thank you again. By the way, absolutely, I'll be removing the `->` marker.

Comment: if you can, do the processing on a bigger system with more RAM and then copy the result to the older machine.

Comment: also, if/when you have future questions, [please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).   Many people here ignore questions with images of text (images are useless, text is usable for testing scripts with, and real data is better than made-up data), and not many will go to the trouble of using an OCR tool to convert it to text.  I know that I wouldn't have bothered if the question hadn't already grabbed my interest.

Comment: `->` as the delimiter is a good idea. I should have thought of that.    BTW, I personally use `pdftotext -layout` rather then pdfgrep, edit a little with vim, cleanup with some custom perl scripts (including one to turn multi-column text into single column, which is one of the reasons for editing with vim, I've found it's easier and much more reliable to manually insert a tab between columns - vim's Ctrl-V helps a lot for this - than to depend on multiple-spaces between columns. This is tedious but beats getting text from different columns jumbled together), and then more vim.

Comment: @zevzek Thank you. The reason why I'm doing all of this is because a TXT file with just text is far more easier to manage on different computer systems as long as `grep` is available I'll have access to thousands of definitions (which is actually my case to be on very bare bones linux boxes). Besides that, thank you for the heads up in regards `->`. :)

Comment: @cas I really appreciate your help, thank you very much. I'll be studying your proposed solution. It could be a "simple" solution but it has so much involved that I think I can learn a lot from this. You are awesome! :) Btw, I added the original text I'm working with and deleted the screenshot.

Comment: @cas Amazing, thank you so much. Even tough a screenshot was not the way to go, it really helps me a lot for future projects to know about `tesseract-ocr`.

Comment: No problem.  BTW, you may also be interested in [ocrmypdf](https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF), a program that extracts each page from a PDF file, runs them through tesseract-ocr and makes a new PDF with the OCR-ed text as a text layer (or which have bad text layers).   Very useful for PDFs that don't already have a text layer.   Also BTW, you don't say what distro you're using but both ocrmypdf and tesseract-ocr are available as packages for debian (and related distros like ubuntu and mint), and probably other distros too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to do it in a single script using the `N;P;D` pattern:

```
sed -e ':loop' -e '$!N;/\n->/!s/-*\n/ /;tloop' -e 'P;D'
```

You loop over adding the 'N'ext line and removing the newlines with optional dash (`s/-*\n/ /`), until the new line starts with `->`.